# Why won't my css3 animation animate in reverse?

Tags: animation, css, hover, rotation

I have a simple animation that has an element roll in on hover, then roll out on mouse-out:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes swing {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);}
    100%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(0);}
}
@-moz-keyframes swing {
    0%   { -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);}
    100%   { -moz-transform: rotate(0);}
}
a#element{  
    margin-left: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: margin-left 1s ease;
    transition: margin-left 1s ease;
}
#element:hover a#element-color{
    -webkit-animation: swing 1s 0 1 alternate forwards; 
    -moz-animation: swing 1s 0 1 normal forwards; 
    animation: swing 1s 0 1 alternate forwards; 
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

This works fine on the rolling in, but when I mouse out, the element flips back 180deg, then animates out. The only thing that isn't working is the rotate backwards; this "just happens", rather than animating.

Comment: Could you add the HTML you're using? And just a guess, but I think you have the selectors wrong (`a#element` and `#element:hover a#element-color` is impossible since `a` cannot be the child of another `a`, and only one ID of any value is allowed in a single document). Even better: a link to an example on [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Also, `forwardsf` in `animation:...;` should be `forward`.

Comment: I fixed the misspelling in the code. Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eubYk/ I used the term "element" in the code above so it was legible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply get rid of the animation and set a transition on the `transform` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/eubYk/2/)):

```
<span id="google-plus-ghost" class="sm-button">
 <a href="/" class="sm-link" id="google-plus-color">Google Plus</a>
</span>
<span id="twitter-ghost" class="sm-button">
 <a href="/" class="sm-link" id="twitter-color">Google Plus</a>
</span>
<span id="linkedin-ghost" class="sm-button">
 <a href="/" class="sm-link" id="linkedin-color">Google Plus</a>
</span>
<span id="facebook-ghost" class="sm-button">
 <a href="/" class="sm-link" id="facebook-color">Google Plus</a>
</span>​
```

```css
.sm-button, .sm-link{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 64px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -999999px;
    width: 64px;
}
.sm-button{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#google-plus-ghost{
    background: transparent url(http://healthfreakgeek.com/wp-content/themes/nathanstaines-starkers-html5-b101efa/images/googlePlusGhost.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
#twitter-ghost{
    background: transparent url(http://healthfreakgeek.com/wp-content/themes/nathanstaines-starkers-html5-b101efa/images/twitterGhost.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 10px;
}
#linkedin-ghost{
    background: transparent url(http://healthfreakgeek.com/wp-content/themes/nathanstaines-starkers-html5-b101efa/images/linkedinGhost.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 5px;
}
#facebook-ghost{
    background: transparent url(http://healthfreakgeek.com/wp-content/themes/nathanstaines-starkers-html5-b101efa/images/facebookGhost.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
a#google-plus-color{
    background: transparent url(http://healthfreakgeek.com/wp-content/themes/nathanstaines-starkers-html5-b101efa/images/googlePlusColor.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
a#twitter-color{
    background: transparent url(http://healthfreakgeek.com/wp-content/themes/nathanstaines-starkers-html5-b101efa/images/twitterColor.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
a#linkedin-color{
    background: transparent url(http://healthfreakgeek.com/wp-content/themes/nathanstaines-starkers-html5-b101efa/images/linkedinColor.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
a#facebook-color{
    background: transparent url(http://healthfreakgeek.com/wp-content/themes/nathanstaines-starkers-html5-b101efa/images/facebookColor.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
a#google-plus-color,
a#twitter-color,
a#linkedin-color,
a#facebook-color {    
    margin-left: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 1s ease, -webkit-transform 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: margin-left 1s ease, -moz-transform 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: margin-left 1s ease, -moz-transform 1s ease;
    -o-transition: margin-left 1s ease, -moz-transform 1s ease;
    transition: margin-left 1s ease, transform 1s swing;
}
#google-plus-ghost:hover a#google-plus-color,
#twitter-ghost:hover a#twitter-color,
#linkedin-ghost:hover a#linkedin-color,
#facebook-ghost:hover a#facebook-color {
    margin-left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}​
```

### Alternate Solution

I played with the code a bit more, and came up with a new version that rolls out from behind the next icon, rather than simply disappearing at a square edge. I also cleaned up the code considerably to get rid of IDs (and make the code reusable). And, just for fun, I made the rolling images start out with `opacity:0;` and **grayscale** (only supported in webkit at the moment I believe, but placeholder code for other engines), and change to fully visible and **color** ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eubYk/5/)):

```
<div class="social-buttons">
    <span class="google-plus ghost">
        <a href="/" class="color">Google Plus</a>
    </span>
    <span class="twitter ghost">
        <a href="/" class="color">Twitter</a>
    </span>
    <span class="linkedin ghost">
        <a href="/" class="color">LinkedIn</a>
    </span>
    <span class="facebook ghost">
        <a href="/" class="color">Facebook</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

```css
.social-buttons {
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    padding-right:64px;
}
.social-buttons .ghost {
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
    margin:10px 0 0 10px;
}
.social-buttons .color {
    display:block;
    height:64px;
    width:64px;
    text-indent: -999999px;
}
.social-buttons .google-plus.ghost {
    z-index:1;
    background: transparent url(http://healthfreakgeek.com/wp-content/themes/nathanstaines-starkers-html5-b101efa/images/googlePlusGhost.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
.social-buttons .twitter.ghost {
    z-index:2;
    background: transparent url(http://healthfreakgeek.com/wp-content/themes/nathanstaines-starkers-html5-b101efa/images/twitterGhost.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
.social-buttons .linkedin.ghost {
    z-index:3;
    background: transparent url(http://healthfreakgeek.com/wp-content/themes/nathanstaines-starkers-html5-b101efa/images/linkedinGhost.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
.social-buttons .facebook.ghost {
    z-index:4;
    background: transparent url(http://healthfreakgeek.com/wp-content/themes/nathanstaines-starkers-html5-b101efa/images/facebookGhost.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
.social-buttons .google-plus a.color {
    background: transparent url(http://healthfreakgeek.com/wp-content/themes/nathanstaines-starkers-html5-b101efa/images/googlePlusColor.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
.social-buttons .twitter a.color {
    background: transparent url(http://healthfreakgeek.com/wp-content/themes/nathanstaines-starkers-html5-b101efa/images/twitterColor.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
.social-buttons .linkedin a.color {
    background: transparent url(http://healthfreakgeek.com/wp-content/themes/nathanstaines-starkers-html5-b101efa/images/linkedinColor.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
.social-buttons .facebook a.color {
    background: transparent url(http://healthfreakgeek.com/wp-content/themes/nathanstaines-starkers-html5-b101efa/images/facebookColor.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
.social-buttons a.color {
    opacity:0;
    margin-left: 100%;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(1);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(1);
    -o-filter: grayscale(1);
    filter: grayscale(1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.social-buttons .ghost:hover a.color {
    opacity:1;
    margin-left: 0;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(0);
    -o-filter: grayscale(0);
    filter: grayscale(0);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}​
```

Comment: Awesome, I knew it was something small like that. I tried that but I was trying to use rotate instead of transform. Hindsight is 20/20, huh?

Comment: @dcp3450, just to push my abilities a bit, I added a [second solution](http://jsfiddle.net/eubYk/5/) to my answer that causes the icons to roll out from behind the next icon, start grayscale (in webkit) and transparent, and end in color. (And, if you use it, can you let me know so I can remove the first solution?)

Comment: **+1** @bfrohs, WOW! Your second solution is working brilliantly in Firefox v14. Cheers!